# Can't import proto file from java file Intellij id

Tags: java, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm trying to import a proto file from a java file in IntelliJ IDEA.

I have a file called A.proto and a file called B.java. I try to import a class `Info` from the A.proto file in the B.java file like this:

```
import A.Info;
```

However, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't look to support proto files and says my class doesn't exist. I installed both plugins `Protobuf Support` and `Protocol Buffer Editor`. But it still doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Problem

IntelliJ recognizes protocol buffer files, but they are not Java, so the Java Compiler doesn't know what to do with them.

## Solution with Maven

You can compile those protocol buffers to Java files, which is the step you are currently missing. The best way I know is to use a Maven plugin to do this.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
            <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <protocVersion>3.0.0</protocVersion> <!-- 2.4.1, 2.5.0, 2.6.1, 3.0.0 -->
                        <includeDirectories>
                            <include>src/main/resources/protobuf</include>
                        </includeDirectories>
                        <inputDirectories>
                            <include>src/main/resources/protobuf/</include>
                        </inputDirectories>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And dependency for the Protocol Buffer classes:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
  <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.11.4</version>
</dependency>
```

With this plugin, Intellij will find the created Java classes, after having initially created the sources. **This way, only your Protocol Buffer files need to be in Source Control. You let the plugin take care of the compilation to Java.**

After creation of the Java classes, you can use them in the rest of your code. **You can even view the generated Java classes in the target/generated-sources** folder in your Maven Project.

Here's what the mapping between Protocol Buffers and Java looks like:

**DistanceWalked.proto**

```
package example;

message DistanceWalked {
    string userId = 1;
    double distance = 2;
}
```

**DistanceWalkedOuterClass.DistanceWalked.java (generated)**

```
package example;

public class DistanceWalked {
 //properties This class isn't pretty...
}
```

(Full code example with protocol buffers and Maven plugin can be found here: https://github.com/TomCools/protocol-buffers-example)

Link to plugin source: https://github.com/os72/protoc-jar-maven-plugin

## Solution without Maven

Without Maven, you have to download the command-line compiler. Documentation on that can be found here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#compiling-your-protocol-buffers

Comment: I have a Maven project and I already tried this plugin but it still doesn't work...

Comment: You have the project in Git somewhere? I could have a quick look.
I have linked my personal project in my solution above. Maybe you can quickly check it out and see if it works for you?

Comment: The package name for my protocol buffers. Name comes from a hobby project where i tried to emulate Pokemon Go with protocol buffers. 

Besides the package name, it's irrelevant.

I have added unit tests to show how the protocol buffers work. You should check that out.

Comment: My proto buffers are in the main/src/ressources/protobuf directory, how do I import them from the /main/src/java/example/A.java ?

Comment: First run mvn clean package. The plugin will create Java Classes for you, with the Protocol Buffer package being the Java Package and the name of the Message as the class name.

Comment: It should generate the classes somewhere in the target/generated-sources folder.

Comment: I only have the target/annotations folder.

Comment: I think the only thing it does is to copy my proto file in target/clasees/protobuf/...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211906/discussion-between-tom-cools-and-paul-beneteau).

Answer (score 2):

The proto file is just the description of the message format. It does not contain code that can be interpreted directly in a java context.
The idea of the proto file is to provide a generic, language agnostic specification of the message format.

Based on the proto file, you can generate the corresponding java code. This code can then be used and imported in your java project.

Have a look here on how to generate code from a proto file: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#compiling-your-protocol-buffers

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone is still stuck -

I found that specifying the path to Intellij fixes the problem:

Preferences -> Languages and Frameworks -> Protocol Buffer -> Uncheck "Configure automatically"

And then add the path to the file.

It should be good for xolstice or os72!